# How i can change the user using django-auth-adfs

Tags: adfs3.0

The authorization [demonstrated on django-auth-adfs](https://github.com/jobec/django-auth-adfs/tree/master/demo/adfs) works perfectly, when you click Login, it comes under the current domain user.

The question is, how can I make it possible to authorize another user?
That is, enter the login (e-mail) and the password for the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking as the author of django-auth-adfs:

That's one of the downsides of seamless SSO. It automatically uses the logged on user. And while it really is a nice user experience, there are indeed situations where it might not be wanted.

For ADFS 4.0 on windows server 2016, there's a possibility to send the `prompt` parameter and set it to `login` to force ADFS to show a login page.

I'll see if I can implement such functionality in a next release. It's really nothing more then an extra setting and sending an extra query parameter to the ADFS upon login.